# Observable Type does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'?

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
@Observable
final class Car: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    var id = UUID()
    var year:Int
    var make:String
    var model:String
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    init(year: Int, make: String, model: String) {
        self.year = year
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
    }
    
}
```

It does not compile:

> Type 'Car' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Is it possible to make it conform to Equatable?

Comment: I don't know the fix, but the cause is the use of `@Observable`. Remove that and the error goes away.

Comment: That’s true. If I use ObservableObject instead it works. 

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 15 beta 6

A bit of WTF to me, but this is the workaround which works for me - found accidentally ofc.

The `(Swift.==)` has to be in the `extension`, otherwise it doesn't work...

```
@Observable public final class Evaluable2: ParseObject {
    
    public var originalData: Data?
    
    public var objectId: String?
    
    public var createdAt: Date?
    
    public var updatedAt: Date?
    
    public var ACL: ParseSwift.ParseACL?
    
    public init() {
        
    }

}

extension Evaluable2: Equatable {
    
    public static func == (lhs: Evaluable2, rhs: Evaluable2) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the earlier Xcode beta, the compiler gives the errors

> @Observable requires property 'year' to have an initial value (from macro 'Observable')
>
> @Observable requires property 'make' to have an initial value (from macro 'Observable')
>
> @Observable requires property 'model' to have an initial value (from macro 'Observable')

Adding default values to those properties satisfied the compiler and I was able to compile your code.  These initial values will be overwritten by your `init`.

```
@Observable
final class Car: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    var id = UUID()
    var year:Int = 0
    var make:String = ""
    var model:String = ""
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    init(year: Int, make: String, model: String) {
        self.year = year
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
    }
    
}
```

**Update**

Something went wrong with my Beta update and I wasn't actually on Beta 4.

Once I did complete the update to Beta 4, I got the *Observable Type does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'* error.

Running a build and checking the build output reveals the error:

> Multiple matching functions named '==' with type '(Car, Car) -> Bool'

Both declarations are showing on the same line.

You should submit beta feedback

Comment: are you on beta 4?

Comment: I thought I was, but something was broken in the update.  Once I updated to Beta 4 I got the error

Comment: ok, because I couldn't understand why I wasn't able to make it work on 4. Thanks